# Get percentage of appearance of a certain value in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I like to get the percentage of a certain version. If stored the info in `mytable`:

```
ID | name | version
===================
 1 | foo  | 1.0
 2 | bar  | 1.0
 3 | loo  | 1.1
 4 | zoo  | 1.2
```

I like to get this result

```
version | percentage
====================
 1.0    | 0.500
 1.1    | 0.250
 1.2    | 0.250
```

My statement is currently (without percentage)

```
SELECT a.version, FROM mytable AS a GROUP BY version ORDER BY version ASC
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query should work:

```
select version, count(*) / const.cnt
from mytable cross join
     (select count(*) as cnt from mytable) const
group by version
order by version;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `COUNT`

```
SELECT version, COUNT(version)/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table)
FROM table
GROUP BY version
```

Comment: @Strawberry: I don't but change a little.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.version, count(*)/full.full_count as percentage
FROM mytable AS a,
     (SELECT count(*) as full_count  FROM mytable) as full
GROUP BY version 
ORDER BY version ASC
```