# Get percentage of appearance of a certain value in mysql 2

Tags: mysql

In addition to [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22456554/get-percentage-of-appearance-of-a-certain-value-in-mysql) I have to respect another column "`post_id`":

```
ID | name | version | post_id
=============================
 1 | foo  | 1.0     |  2
 2 | bar  | 1.0     |  2
 3 | loo  | 1.1     |  1
 4 | zoo  | 1.2     |  2
```

The output should now be:

```
version | percentage | post_id
===============================
 1.0    | 0.667      | 2
 1.1    | 1.000      | 1
 1.2    | 0.333      | 2
```

[**The solution by Gordon Linoff**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22456554/get-percentage-of-appearance-of-a-certain-value-in-mysql#22456717) is working pretty well except it calculates the percentage of all entries (obviously):

```
SELECT version, 
       Count(*) / const.cnt 
FROM   mytable 
       CROSS JOIN (SELECT Count(*) AS cnt 
                   FROM   mytable) const 
GROUP  BY version 
ORDER  BY version;
```

**EDIT** (this is not what I want!)

adding just post_id to the select wouldn't bring the expected result:

```
SELECT version, 
       Count(*) / const.cnt,
       post_id
FROM   mytable 
       ....
```

The output would be

```
version | percentage | post_id
===============================
 1.0    | 0.500      | 2
 1.1    | 0.250      | 1
 1.2    | 0.250      | 2
```

**EDIT** Here's a fiddle of the first idea: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f738d/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think this will do it:-

```
SELECT version, 
       Count(*) / const.cnt ,
       mytable.post_id
FROM   mytable 
INNER JOIN (SELECT post_id, Count(*) AS cnt 
           FROM   mytable
           GROUP BY post_id) const 
ON mytable.post_id = const.post_id
GROUP  BY version, post_id
ORDER  BY version;
```

Sub query gets the number of records for each post id, and then this count is used to calculate the fraction that are for this version.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand the question you want to add `post_id` to the columns you select,

```
   SELECT version, 
          Count(*) / const.cnt,
          post_id
   -- snip ---
```

Comment: That would be easy :). Unfortunately the percentage doesn't match in that case. If you sum all percentage you'll get `1` but it should be one for every post (hope that makes sense)

Comment: wait do you want to goup by both post_id and percentage?

Comment: Have no idea if a group helps. I like to get the view from the question where the sum of the percentage for a certain `post_id` is `1`

Answer (score 0):

I have a nice and fully functional solution,  that involves both mysql and your scripting language,  and looping through the table:

First query each post_id value and assign it to a variable. This can be done with a scripting language such as **PHP**.  Something like:

```
Select distinct(post_id) from table.
```

Then create the loop in your language,  for example in **PHP**:

```
foreach($query as $value)
  {  // and here,  inside the loop again query the table but with variables:
     set @pid=$value;
     SELECT version, count(*)/(select count(*) from table where post_id=@pid) as                 percentage, post_id FROM `table` where post_id=@pid group by 1
  }
```

Again,  back to scripting language,  deploy data.  You'll get the percentages as you requested,  weighted for each post_id by each version.

Please test it, I did it and worked as requested.

Comment: Thnks but as mentioned I don't like a request for each post_id

Comment: Simple plain statistics: You want to weight each post_id in relation to it's different versions.  To do so,  you must indeed,  weight each post_id.  There are two ways to do it,  1) the solution I posted,  which works fine, 2) to use a while loop inside the mysql statement.   But have in mind that mathematically,  it's the way: weight each post_id in relation to it's version.

Comment: Can you update my fiddle somehow: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f738d/1
I can get an array of post_id's but is it required since they are in the table as well?

Comment: Also keep in mind that the use of control structures like loops,  doesn't affect performance.  This is a very tiny loop which by no means affects server response or user experience.